# .net to mono RSACryptoServiceProvider not working

Tags: c#, encryption, mono

I'm currently porting one of my library to mono to make it usable with MonoMac.
I use RSA in this library, and it's not working the same way : it's working well with .Net Framework 4 but with mono it's not working anymore...

I'm using RSA to exchange keys, here is the server side code :

```
private void SecureConnection()
{
    RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = RSA.ExportParameters(false);
    NetStream.Write(RSAKeyInfo.Modulus, 0, RSAKeyInfo.Modulus.Length);
    NetStream.Flush ();
    byte[] keyReceived = new byte[128];
    byte[] IvReceived = new byte[128];
    int position = 0;
    while (position < 127) {
        position += NetStream.Read (keyReceived, position, 128 - position);
    }
    position = 0;
    while (position < 127) {
        position += NetStream.Read (IvReceived, position, 128 - position);
    }
    byte[] realKey = RSA.Decrypt(keyReceived, true);
    byte[] realIv = RSA.Decrypt(IvReceived, true);
    Rijndael = new RijndaelManaged { Key = realKey, IV = realIv };
    Encrypt = Rijndael.CreateEncryptor();
    Decrypt = Rijndael.CreateDecryptor();
    FullName = WaitAndGetString();
    Debug.WriteLine("[TCP] TcpHandler -> Connection to {0} ({1}) secured successfully", TcpClient.RemoteEndPoint, FullName);
}
```

And here is the client side implementation :

```
private ConnectedClient SecureConnection(TcpClient toSecure)
{
     NetworkStream netStr = toSecure.GetStream();
     ConnectedClient cc = new ConnectedClient
     {
        TcpClient = toSecure,
        NetStream = netStr
     };
     byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
     int position = 0;
     while (position < 127) 
     {
         position += netStr.Read (buffer, position, 128 - position);
     }
     RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
     RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = new RSAParameters
     {
        Exponent = new byte[] {1, 0, 1}, 
        Modulus = buffer
     };
     RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);
     Rijndael rjindael = new RijndaelManaged();
     rjindael.GenerateKey();
     rjindael.GenerateIV();
     byte[] keyToSend = RSA.Encrypt(rjindael.Key, true);
     byte[] IvToSend = RSA.Encrypt(rjindael.IV, true);
     netStr.Write(keyToSend, 0, 128);
     netStr.Flush();
     netStr.Write(IvToSend, 0, 128);
     netStr.Flush();
     cc.Encrypt = rjindael.CreateEncryptor();
     cc.Decrypt = rjindael.CreateDecryptor();
     cc.Rijndael = rjindael;
     Debug.WriteLine("[TCP] ConnectedClient -> Connection to " + toSecure.Client.RemoteEndPoint + " secured successfully");
     cc.WriteOnStream(SharedGlobals.FullUsername);
     return cc;
}
```

The problem is on the client side : 
`byte[] realKey = RSA.Decrypt(keyReceived, true);`
Is throwing a `CryptographicException` with `OAEP decoding error`

This exception is only thrown with Mono, not with standard .Net

Any ideas why ?

Comment: First problem: you're calling `Stream.Read` and completely ignoring the result. How do you know that you've completely read the key and IV?

Comment: I'll try to loop until I've got the good size, and I'll update my question.

Comment: Edited my post, I'm still having the same issue

Comment: You are instantiating a goodly number of objects whose classes implement the `IDisposable` interface. You should be wrapping their lifetimes in a `using` statement.

Comment: Sorry, but your read method is still not used correctly, you should read until your stream returns `0`, and *please* use `buffer.Length` instead of repeating literals everywhere.

Comment: At this time I'm sure about the size of what is going to be read, is it a complete necessity ? If yes, can you explain me why ?

Comment: 1) Your client assumes that e=65537, but I don't think the docs for `new RSACryptoServiceProvider` guarantee that this is the case. I also don't see a guarantee that 1024 bit keys are generated. 2) Dump the byte arrays (hex encoded) to the console at several points in the program so you can see where the error is introduced by checking if the bytes are the same on the server and on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused because the exponent is not the same between .Net and Mono. .Net always generate a `byte[]{1,0,1}` (at least from what I saw). So, now I send the exponent with the public key, it's working well.